# how to save HTML code of a URL in a string in Android

Tags: android, html

I am trying to get HTML source code from a Url ... I added up permission of INTERNET as well but still I couldnot get the HTML code in string ... my application just crash ... am using this on Android 4.2 ...i have also loaded same page in webview and webview is displaying the page ...Please help me ...

I am using following code

```
public String getXml(String url) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
        return page;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

I want to ask another question as well
what if I have to get the HTML source code of a webpage which is already downloaded ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing network operation on main Thread that result to exception.

```
NetworkOnMainThreadException.
```

So use AsyncTask to do network operation on android version >= 3.0.

### EDIT

To learn about How to perform operation in AsyncTask.

[Look Android developer docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @Imran I have updated answer and you can learn now about AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Do what @TGMCians said, and put this in an AsyncTask. But to get the returned HTML in a string, do:

```
String responseEntity = EntityUtils.toString(page.getEntity);
```

and that should have your HTML in it.

Comment: can u please guide me how to use async task ... actually am new to android

Comment: Best place to look is in the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html 
They have some good examples.